# GCC 6.2 build error in HP-UX

Tags: unix, gcc

### **Build Environment**

- HP-UX RX2660 B.11.31 U ia64
- GCC 4.2.3

### **Build Target**

- GCC 6.2

### **swlist**

> Product(s) not contained in a Bundle:
>   gcc - 4.2.3
>   gettext - 0.19.8.1
>   gmp - 6.1.2
>   gnutls - 3.6.0
>   intltool - 0.51.0
>   libffi - 3.2.1
>   libgcc - 4.2.3
>   libiconv - 1.15
>   libidn2 - 2.0.4
>   libtasn1 - 4.12
>   libunistring - 0.9.7
>   libzip - 1.3.0
>   lzlib - 1.9
>   make - 4.2.1
>   mpc - 1.0.3
>   nettle - 3.3
>   p11_kit - 0.23.8
>   pcre - 8.41
>   wget - 1.19.1
>   zlib - 1.2.11

---

> $ ./configure --prefix=/home/gcc-6.2.0.bin --enable-checking=release --enable-languages=c,c++ --disable-multilib
>   checking build system type... ia64-hp-hpux11.31
>   checking host system type... ia64-hp-hpux11.31
>   checking target system type... ia64-hp-hpux11.31
>   checking for a BSD-compatible install... ./install-sh -c
>   checking whether ln works... yes
>   checking whether ln -s works... yes
>   checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /usr/bin/sed
>   checking for gawk... no
>   checking for mawk... no
>   checking for nawk... no
>   checking for awk... awk
>   checking for libsanitizer support... no
>   checking for libvtv support... no
>   checking for libmpx support... no
>   checking for gcc... gcc
>   checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
>   checking whether the C compiler works... yes
>   checking whether we are cross compiling... no
>   checking for suffix of executables...
>   checking for suffix of object files... o
>   checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
>   checking whether gcc accepts -g... yes
>   checking for gcc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
>   checking for g++... g++
>   checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... yes
>   checking whether g++ accepts -g... yes
>   checking whether g++ accepts -static-libstdc++ -static-libgcc... no
>   checking for gnatbind... no
>   checking for gnatmake... no
>   checking whether compiler driver understands Ada... no
>   checking how to compare bootstrapped objects... cmp $$f1 $$f2 16 16
>   checking for objdir... .libs
>   checking for isl 0.16, 0.15, or deprecated 0.14... no
>   recommended isl version is 0.16 or 0.15, the minimum required isl version 0.14 is >deprecated
>   checking for isl 0.16 or 0.15... no
>   *** This configuration is not supported in the following subdirectories:
>       target-libsanitizer target-libvtv target-libmpx target-liboffloadmic
>      (Any other directories should still work fine.)
>   checking for default BUILD_CONFIG...
>   checking for --enable-vtable-verify... no
>   checking for bison... no
>   checking for byacc... no
>   checking for yacc... yacc
>   checking for bison... no
>   checking for gm4... no
>   checking for gnum4... no
>   checking for m4... m4
>   checking for flex... no
>   checking for lex... lex
>   checking for flex... no
>   checking for makeinfo... no
>   /home/gcc-6.2.0/missing[81]: makeinfo:  not found.
>   checking for expect... no
>   checking for runtest... no
>   checking for ar... ar
>   checking for as... as
>   checking for dlltool... no
>   checking for ld... (cached) /usr/ccs/bin/ld
>   checking for lipo... no
>   checking for nm... nm
>   checking for ranlib... ranlib
>   checking for strip... strip
>   checking for windres... no
>   checking for windmc... no
>   checking for objcopy... objcopy
>   checking for objdump... objdump
>   checking for readelf... readelf
>   checking for cc... cc
>   checking for c++... c++
>   checking for gcc... gcc
>   checking for gcj... no
>   checking for gfortran... no
>   checking for gccgo... no
>   checking for ar... ar
>   checking for as... as
>   checking for dlltool... no
>   checking for ld... ld
>   checking for lipo... no
>   checking for nm... nm
>   checking for objcopy... objcopy
>   checking for objdump... objdump
>   checking for ranlib... ranlib
>   checking for readelf... readelf
>   checking for strip... strip
>   checking for windres... no
>   checking for windmc... no
>   checking where to find the target ar... host tool
>   checking where to find the target as... host tool
>   checking where to find the target cc... host tool
>   checking where to find the target c++... host tool
>   checking where to find the target c++ for libstdc++... host tool
>   checking where to find the target dlltool... host tool
>   checking where to find the target gcc... host tool
>   checking where to find the target gcj... host tool
>   checking where to find the target gfortran... host tool
>   checking where to find the target gccgo... host tool
>   checking where to find the target ld... host tool
>   checking where to find the target lipo... host tool
>   checking where to find the target nm... host tool
>   checking where to find the target objcopy... host tool
>   checking where to find the target objdump... host tool
>   checking where to find the target ranlib... host tool
>   checking where to find the target readelf... host tool
>   checking where to find the target strip... host tool
>   checking where to find the target windres... host tool
>   checking where to find the target windmc... host tool
>   checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles... no
>   configure: creating ./config.status
>   config.status: creating Makefile

---

> $ make
>   Make: Don't know how to make all-@USE_INCLUDED_LIBINTL@.  Stop.

I do not understand the error for the make command. I do not know what "USE_INCLUDED_LIBINTL @" means. How do I fix this?

Comment: we need to see the contents of the `makefile` created from running `./configure`. You could also just say `./configure ....` ran without generating errors or warnings or any reference to USE_INCLUDED_LIBINTL. Good luck.

Comment: @shellter I added `export SHLIB_PATH = / usr / local / include / libintl.h` to .profile because I do not think I can refer to the file` libintl.h`. I do not know what the error log means.

Answer (score 2):

`./configure` means that you are running the `configure` script from within the GCC source tree.  This is not supported.  You need to create a new directory and run `configure` within that.

You also need to run GNU make, not make.  The error message comes from HP-UX make, which is not suitable for building GCC.

The lack of the `@…@` pattern substitution could be a bug in HP-UX sed.  Try installing GNU sed that and see that it helps (but it is not currently listed as a build requirement for GCC).

Comment: Your advice is to create a directory called "/home/gcc-6.2.0.bin" and run the configure command inside it.
`/home/gcc-6.2.0.bin] # /home/gcc-6.2.0/configure`

The above command was executed normally, but gmake still does not run with the following logs.
`gmake: *** No rule to make target '../config.status', needed by 'Makefile'. Stop.`

Comment: If the `configure` command computed normally, it should have create a `config.status` file. (I assume the reference to `../config.status` comes from one of the subdirectory makefiles.)

Comment: `[RX2660$:/home/gcc-6.2.0.bin]# cp config.status ../config.status`config.status Recognition has been resolved ... but gmake has the same error as make ... `gmake: *** No rule to make target 'all- @ USE_INCLUDED_LIBINTL @', needed by 'all'. Stop.`

Comment: @string@   << What does this mean? It seems to refer to something, but it does not refer to it in the Makefile. There are so many places to use ...

Comment: YunjinJang, the lack of `@…@` substitution could be a sed bug.